# How to keep buttons on the right side but vertically centered?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I have this list of texts with a button for each row on the right side. How can I make the buttons stay on the right side but vertically centered? if I have a lot of text in a row the buttons aren't vertically centered. Thanks a lot in advanced! Here's my code:

```css
ol > li.row {
   position: relative;
   list-style: none;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   border-bottom-color: #ccc;
}

.right-side {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   padding: 15px;   
 }
```

```html
<ol>
    <li class="row">
        <h3>Text 1</h3>
        <div class="right-side">
            <button>botton 1</button>
        </div>

    </li>
    <li class="row">
        <h3>Text 2</h3>
        <div class="right-side">
            <button>botton 2</button>
        </div>
        <p>This is some random text</p>
    </li>
    <li class="row">
        <h3>Text 3</h3>
        <div class="right-side">
            <button>botton 3</button>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="row">
        <h3>Text 4</h3>
        <div class="right-side">
            <button>botton 4</button>
        </div>
        <p>This is another random text</p>
        <p>abc</p>
    </li>
    <li class="row">
        <h3>Text 5</h3>
        <div class="right-side">
            <button>botton 5</button>
        </div>
        <p>efg</p>
        <p>random text</p>
        <p>This is another paragraph</p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

**NOTE:** I prefer not to use Flex

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the top to top: 50%;, and add: transform: translate(0, -50%);  to your .right-side class

```
.right-side {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translate(0, -50%);
   right: 0;
   padding: 15px;
}
```

```css
ol > li.row {
   position: relative;
   list-style: none;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   border-bottom-color: #ccc; 
}
.right-side {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   transform: translate(0, -50%);
   right: 0;
   padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li class="row">
        <h3>Text 1</h3>
        <div class="right-side">
            <button>botton 1</button>
        </div>

    </li>
    <li class="row">
        <h3>Text 2</h3>
        <div class="right-side">
            <button>botton 2</button>
        </div>
        <p>This is some random text</p>
    </li>
    <li class="row">
        <h3>Text 3</h3>
        <div class="right-side">
            <button>botton 3</button>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="row">
        <h3>Text 4</h3>
        <div class="right-side">
            <button>botton 4</button>
        </div>
        <p>This is another random text</p>
        <p>abc</p>
    </li>
    <li class="row">
        <h3>Text 5</h3>
        <div class="right-side">
            <button>botton 5</button>
        </div>
        <p>efg</p>
        <p>random text</p>
        <p>This is another paragraph</p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use flex and restructure your html markup. Typically you want the html structure to be grouped the same way you are viewing it on the screen. So I would vote for this option since the div for left-side are grouping these together as opposed to using position absolute / relative.

```css
ol > li.row {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
   list-style: none;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   border-bottom-color: #ccc;
   width: 100%;
}

.right-side {
   padding: 15px;   
   align-self: center;
 }
```

```html
<ol>
    <li class="row">
        <div class="left-side">
            <h3>Text 1</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="right-side">
            <button>botton 1</button>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="row">
        <div class="left-side">
            <h3>Text 2</h3>
            <p>This is some random text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="right-side">
            <button>botton 2</button>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="row">
        <div class="left-side">
            <h3>Text 3</h3>
            <p>This is some random text</p>
        </div>
        <div class="right-side">
            <button>botton 3</button>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="row">
        <div>
            <h3>Text 4</h3>
            <p>This is another random text</p>
            <p>abc</p>
        </div>
        <div class="right-side">
            <button>botton 4</button>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="row">
        <div>
            <h3>Text 5</h3>
            <p>efg</p>
            <p>random text</p>
            <p>This is another paragraph</p>
        </div>
        <div class="right-side">
            <button>botton 5</button>
        </div>
    </li>
</ol>
```

If you have to this html structure you can still use flex, but the parent li will need the height set so it knows where center is. You can use -webkit-fill-available for this.

```css
ol > li.row {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom-color: #ccc;
    height: -webkit-fill-available;
}

.right-side {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    height: -webkit-fill-available;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li class="row">
        <h3>Text 1</h3>
        <div class="right-side">
            <button>botton 1</button>
        </div>

    </li>
    <li class="row">
        <h3>Text 2</h3>
        <div class="right-side">
            <button>botton 2</button>
        </div>
        <p>This is some random text</p>
    </li>
    <li class="row">
        <h3>Text 3</h3>
        <div class="right-side">
            <button>botton 3</button>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="row">
        <h3>Text 4</h3>
        <div class="right-side">
            <button>botton 4</button>
        </div>
        <p>This is another random text</p>
        <p>abc</p>
    </li>
    <li class="row">
        <h3>Text 5</h3>
        <div class="right-side">
            <button>botton 5</button>
        </div>
        <p>efg</p>
        <p>random text</p>
        <p>This is another paragraph</p>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I prefer not to use flex as this is moving a lot of pieces around my actual application. Do you have another way to accomplish this?

Comment: You could not use flex and just set `top: 50%` on the `right side` but the parent is going to need a height.

Answer (score -1):

```css
   
ol > li.row {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom-color: #ccc;
}

.right-side {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li class="row">
        <h3>Text 1</h3>
        <div class="right-side">
            <button>botton 1</button>
        </div>

    </li>
    <li class="row">
        <h3>Text 2</h3>
        <div class="right-side">
            <button>botton 2</button>
        </div>
        <p>This is some random text</p>
    </li>
    <li class="row">
        <h3>Text 3</h3>
        <div class="right-side">
            <button>botton 3</button>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="row">
        <h3>Text 4</h3>
        <div class="right-side">
            <button>botton 4</button>
        </div>
        <p>This is another random text</p>
        <p>abc</p>
    </li>
    <li class="row">
        <h3>Text 5</h3>
        <div class="right-side">
            <button>botton 5</button>
        </div>
        <p>efg</p>
        <p>random text</p>
        <p>This is another paragraph</p>
    </li>
</ol>

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:
[![centered buttons][1]][1]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).